# Tkinter - Frame background changes after minimizing and restoring the root

Tags: python, tkinter

```
buttonLeft=Tk.Frame(self,width=60,height=60,highlightbackground='white',background='',highlightthickness=3)
buttonLeft.place(x=50,y=height/2 - buttonLeft['height']/2)
```

Here, I want the background color to be transparent. When I open the app, its transparent, but when I minimize my tk app and restore it back, the background color changes to 'black'. How do I stop this?

Comment: You could try leaving the keyworded argument "background" out. If that does not work, please provide us a bit more context (i.e. source code).

Comment: tkinter widgets do not support transparent background.